# couchbase consistency in node.js sdk 3

Tags: sdk, couchbase, sql++

in couchbase SDK version 3 I can't find consistency set in the insert and find query like java

```
N1qlParams adhoc2 = N1qlParams.build().consistency(ScanConsistency.STATEMENT_PLUS).adhoc(true);
```

is that deprecated?
and if it's deprecated how can I fix this problem?

regards.

Answer (score 3):

checkout options of cluster.query()

https://docs.couchbase.com/sdk-api/couchbase-node-client/Cluster.html#query

Answer (score 1):

Check out the class QueryScanConsistency

```
cluster.query(queryString, QueryOptions.queryOptions()
            .scanConsistency(QueryScanConsistency.REQUEST_PLUS) )
            .rowsAs(MyEntity.class)
```

You should use REQUEST_PLUS instead of STATEMENT_PLUS